# Old rust code with string append breaks with nightly

Tags: string, rust

I have a line in some of my older rust code that uses `append()`, I checked the recent docs and append seem's to have been removed from `std::string::String`. my line of code is:

```
hex_to_bin(x).to_string().append(hex_to_bin(y))

main.rs:34:29: 34:50 error: type `collections::string::String` does not implement any method in scope named `append`
main.rs:34   hex_to_bin(x).to_string().append(hex_to_bin(y))
```

so according to the docs I thought `push_str()` would be the same, but when switched I get

```
main.rs:34:3: 34:52 error: mismatched types: expected `collections::string::String`, found `()` (expected struct collections::string::String, found ())
main.rs:34   hex_to_bin(x).to_string().push_str(hex_to_bin(y))
```

how can I convert this line of code correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push_str` is declared as:

```
fn push_str(&mut self, string: &str)
```

This means it operates on a mutable String, and returns `()`. Without seeing the rest of your code, my guess is that you're trying to pass the result of `push_str` to something that is expecting a String - perhaps you're expecting to assign the result to a String? Instead you would want to maintain a mutable String and call `push_str` to append the `hex_to_bin(y)` to it.